# Find a time pattern within a string

Tags: vb.net

My string variable may or may not contain the time, it may be anywhere within a group of words. `now is 03:24` or any other possible combination of words or location with in the string. The only constant is that it will be **xx:xx**. I would like to detect the `true` or `false` of the **xx:xx** pattern within the string.

I have been playing with Regex and other solutions but I am nowhere. I'm not even sure if what I have, (collected bits and pieces) actually will work.

Comment: if you're not sure it will work, have you considered testing it against a range of expected values, and seeing what happens? And we can't help you fix it, if you don't show it to us. (But using regular expressions is almost certainly the right approach, btw.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Regex.Match` with the pattern `\b\d{2}:\d{2}\b`:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\b\d{2}:\d{2}\b")
Dim match As Match = regex.Match("now is 03:24")
If match.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine("MATCH")
End If
```

The above solution will detect the presence of a timestamp of the form `03:24` anywhere in the input string.

Comment: can now, before it would not let me